# How to use MediaStore to get geo location of image in android

Tags: android

I want to get the latitude and longitude of the image taken.Can we use MediaStore to get the latitude and Longitude.
As MediaStore has these two variables:

```
/**
             * The latitude where the image was captured.
             * <P>Type: DOUBLE</P>
             */
            public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";

            /**
             * The longitude where the image was captured.
             * <P>Type: DOUBLE</P>
             */
            public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";

            /**
```

How to get these values.

Comment: as i understand you want to retrive image's latitude longitude from MediaStore right ?

Comment: yes,i dont want to use EXIF

Comment: haha stack Learner again its you ! well buddy you can simply retrieve it by using MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE in getcontentresolver.query();

Comment: this will return entire column,how to get location of particular image

Comment: Check documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

Comment: you need to query it with search like MediaStore.Images.Media.Data =? where "?" is your image data and you will get latitude according to cursor result